# Is it possible to use WPS Spreadsheets instead of Microsoft Excel for adding an excel source in SSIS

Tags: ssis

While using ssis in visual studio 2019 I am trying to select the name of the excel sheet in the excel source editor but it shows 'No tables or views could be loaded'. Is it because I don't have Microsoft excel installed in my laptop? But I do have WPS spreadsheet which works the same as MS Excel

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). As far as I know, it might be the only provider Visual Studio can use in your case. 32-bit and 64-bit can be existing on the same machine.